# authentication ruby valid_password error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, passwords

I'm new to ROR. I tried for simple login with email and password. I can't authenticate the password. It's repeated question, and my error is not yet cleared with old questions. My code is

```
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
 user.valid_password?(params[:password])

 if @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]).valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
    #render :json=> user.as_json(:status=>'success', :Message=>'Sucessfully Registered', :username=>user.username ), :status=>201
    render :json=> {userDetails: [{:status=>'Success',:Message=>'Successfully Signed in', :username=>@user.name, :useremail=>@user.email, :usermobile=>@user.mobile_no }]}, :status=>200
 else
   render :json=> {:status=>'Failure',:message=>'Invalid Credentials'}, :status=>422
   :message=>'Sucessfully Singed in', :auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email), :status=>201
  end
```

I'm facing the below error

```
undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass
```

could anyone tell me what i'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you add the value of `params` to your question please.  You can see this in your log or server output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the if line to

```
if (@user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])) && @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
```

Comment: same as above mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

`User.find_by_email(params[:email])` returns nil (can't find), thus `user` is nil, and Rails is telling you that the **nil** class doesn't have a `valid_password?` method.

**EDIT**

You are calling a method `User.find_by_email(params[:email])` that has **nil** as result. So in simple words you didn't find records.

**EDIT v2**

You could check the content of user for debugging purpose by using a code like:

```
if !user.nil?
  puts "#{user}"
else 
  puts "user is nil!"
end
```

Comment: Try to check my edit. In simple word you have to check the results of User.find_by_email(params[:email]) that is nil. So you didn't find any user. so the value of user is nil. And you are try to calling a method on a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

Just check user . I think your query with User.find_by_email(params[:emil])
 return a nil .thats why you getting the undefined method `valid_password?' for nil:NilClass .